# amcharts line to be changed with different color if it goes down to the other line(after intersecting)

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am using amcharts, where in there are two line getting drawn. In case if the first line goes down to the second line, I need to make that part of line - bold with red color.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
                    "backgroundColor": 'blue',
                    "theme": "light",
                    "type": "serial",
                    "zoomOutText": '',
                    "color": "black",
                    "dataDateFormat": "HH:NN",
                    "legend": {
                "useGraphSettings": true
            },
                    "dataProvider": chartData,
                    "valueAxes": [{
                            "id": "v1",
                            "position": "left",
                            "axisColor": "#472F52",
                            "title": "Time of the Day",
                            "type": "date",
                            "axisThickness": 2,
                            "markPeriodChange": false,
                            "autoGridCount": false,
                            "minimumDate": "00:00",
                            "maximumDate": "23:00",                                
                            "gridCount": 20,
                            "minPeriod": "ss",                              
                        }

                    ],
                    "startDuration": 1,
                    "graphs": [{
                            "lineAlpha": 0.9,
                            "type": "line",
                            "lineThickness": 1.5,
                            "bullet": "round",
                            "lineColor": "#0D338C",
                            "bulletBorderColor": "#0D338C",
                            "bulletBorderThickness": 0.2,
                            "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.5,
                            "valueField": "expectedEndTime",
                            "title": "Expected End Time",           
                            "dateFormat": "HH:NN",
                            "labelPosition": "top",
                            "labelColor": "red",
                            "valueAxis": "v1",
                            "labelText": "[[labelExpected]]",
                            "balloonText": "Estimated End Time : <b>[[value]]</b>"
                        },
                        {
                            "lineAlpha": 0.9,
                            "type": "line",
                            "lineThickness": 1.5,
                            "lineColor": "#C63F05",
                            "bullet": "round",
                            "bulletBorderColor": "#C63F05",
                            "bulletBorderThickness": 0.2,
                            "bulletBorderAlpha": 0.5,
                            "valueField": "actualEndTime",
                            "title": "Actual End Time",
                            "dateFormat": "HH:NN",
                            "labelPosition": "bottom",
                            "labelColor": "blue",
                            "valueAxis": "v1",
                            "labelText": "[[labelActual]]",
                            "balloonText": "Actual End Time : <b>[[value]]</b>"
                        }
                    ],
                    "chartCursor": {
                        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "DD",
                        "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
                        "cursorColor": "#000000",
                        "fullWidth": true,
                        "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
                        "zoomable": false
                    },
                    "categoryField": "batchName",
                    "categoryAxis": {
                        "gridPosition": "start",
                        "axisThickness": 2,                         
                        "axisColor": "#472F52",
                        "autoGridCount": false,
                        "gridCount": 1000,
                        "title": "Batches",
                        "labelRotation": 30
                    },
                    "export": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "borderRadius": "10px",
                        "text-align": "center",
                        "pdfMake": {
                            "content": ["'<Name of the Metric to be displayed dynamically>'",
                                "                     ", "from <startDate> To <endDate>", {
                                    "image": "reference", //exported image
                                    "fit": [523.28, 769.89]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "legend": {
                            "position": "bottom", // or "right", "bottom" and "left" are possible
                            "width": 200, // optional
                            "height": 200 // optional
                        }
                    }
                });
```

there are two line getting drawn. In case if the first line goes down to the second line, I need to make that part of line - bold with red color.

Here is  [My JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1r7fq2d/10/)

Any suggestions is deeply appreciated!

Comment: By saying "highlight that part", did you mean you would like to just highlight the individual point when the condition is satisfied? Or you like to highlight/fill the gap between 2 graphs?

Comment: Yeah, preferably i would like to fill the gap. Otherwise, making the line bold with red color also should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `fillAlphas` on 2 graphs, it will fill the area between the graph and the top of the chart with lighter color.

```
graphs: [
    {
        ...,
        fillAlphas: .5
    },
    {
        ...,
        fillAlphas: .5
    }
]
```

The area with 2 colors overlapped are unnecessary but I don't know if there is a way to get rid of it easily. The lighter blue areas are the ones when the first line goes under the second line.

Would this be good enough?

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/mze52096/

[image]

Comment: thanks, but its getting filled for entire graph. I need to highlight only the part where fist line goes down to the second line. please suggest if making the first line bold with red color, can be achieved for that part.

Comment: I understand. I think `AmChart` only provides functionality to fill the gap between 2 lines (https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/filling-area-between-two-lines/), and that will not only fill the areas you want where the first line goes under the second, but also fill the areas where the first line goes above the second as well. My solution in the post is the best I can think of as the light blue areas are indeed the areas you're looking for and they're kind of clear in the chart, despite there are other areas highlighted with other colors you don't need. Let's see if others have other solutions.