# Conditional Chart area fill in amCharts - amStockCharts

Tags: graph, amcharts, amstock

I want to display a graph very similar to below tradingView chart in amCharts. The problem is how can I fill the area between two specific line graphs with different fill color depending on which line graph is above the other.

[image]

Using `fillToGraph` will always fill the same color regardless of whether that graph is below or above the another graph and ends up mixing both the colors as shown below.
[image]

I am using amCharts v3.
Please help.

Comment: You'll need to specify your own colors in your data with `fillColorsField` for instances where the values intersect and provide your own color. Note that you will need to disable data grouping to use `fillColorsField`

Comment: Or you can fill your graphs using `fillAlphas`. The drawback of it is that it also fills the areas when your graphs union. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52955797/2410655

Comment: @DavidLiang My aim is to fill area bwtween two graphs with red when the red line is above green one and fill with green when green is above red. As Iin the second picture, fillAlphas goes both way when used with fillToGraph and the result is a mix of green and red shades.

Comment: @xorspark I want to group data while displaying. was just wondering the use of "useDatasetColors". Is that something relevant here?

Comment: Not really. It lets you override the color locally through `fillColors`/`lineColor` but it doesn't let you control what fill is used for each point. For that you still need `fillColorsField` and disabling data grouping, which will impact performance. My colleague made a serial chart solution a while back using `fillColorsField` through the init handler [here](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/fe3af55227bbf3e3f0c663f974192aaf) that illustrates the how it can work. It can be adapted to the stock chart with some tweaking.